# export 3d object from website

Tags: 3d, export, three.js, blender, 3dsmax

I'm so new at three.js and 3d. I want to create a 3d shape at my website and give some modifiable attributes, so user can modify some parts of this shape(I did this part). Now I want to give user a link to download this modified shape as file which can open at Blender or 3dsmax. I linger on this part. How can I develop such functionality?

Thanks very much for your help

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Please include some code to show
[what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

The full answer is probably beyond the scope of StackOverflow, because what you will need to do to make this work *well* is to develop a web service -- not just a web page. The server-side portion would probably need to do the file-transfer part of the operations.

Are you familiar with http://www.3dtin.com/ which provides some similar general-modeling functionality?

A somewhat ugly way to solve this, if the models are not huge, might be to have some  in your web page that could contain text for an export format like OBJ or STL. They could copy-paste that text.